# Remove duplicates from PySpark array column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark Dataframe that contains an `ArrayType(StringType())` column. This column contains duplicate strings inside the array which I need to remove. For example, one row entry could look like `[milk, bread, milk, toast]`. Let's say my dataframe is named `df` and my column is named `arraycol`. I need something like:

```
df = df.withColumn("arraycol_without_dupes", F.remove_dupes_from_array("arraycol"))
```

My intution was that there exists a simple solution to this, but after browsing stackoverflow for 15 minutes I didn't find anything better than exploding the column, removing duplicates on the complete dataframe, then grouping again. There has *got* to be a simpler way that I just didn't think of, right?

I am using Spark version 2.4.0

Comment: why cant you do: `df = df.dropDuplicates(subset = ["arraycol"])`

Comment: @YOLO: The duplicates are inside the array in a single row... I will reformulate my question to be more precise.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For pyspark version 2.4+, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_distinct
df = df.withColumn("arraycol_without_dupes", array_distinct("arraycol"))
```

---

For older versions, you *can* do this with the API functions using `explode` + `groupBy` and `collect_set`, but a `udf` is probably more efficient here:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

remove_dupes_from_array = udf(lambda row: list(set(row)), ArrayType(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("arraycol_without_dupes", remove_dupes_from_array("arraycol"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I will see whether I can upgrade my cluster to 2.4.0.

Comment: I was able to upgrade my cluster and can confirm that this does exactly what I need.