# pyspark dataframe: remove duplicates in an array column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to remove some duplicated words in a column of pyspark dataframe.

based on [Remove duplicates from PySpark array column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185710/remove-duplicates-from-pyspark-array-column)

My Spark:

```
  2.4.5
```

Py3 code:

```
  test_df = spark.createDataFrame([("I like this Book and this book be DOWNLOADED on line",)], ["text"])
  t3 = test_df.withColumn("text", F.array("text")) # have to convert it to array because the original large df is array type.

  t4 = t3.withColumn('text', F.expr("transform(text, x -> lower(x))"))
  t5 = t4.withColumn('text', F.array_distinct("text"))
  t5.show(1, 120)
```

but got

```
 +--------------------------------------------------------+
 |                                                    text| 
 +--------------------------------------------------------+
 |[i like this book and this book be downloaded on line]|
 +--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to remove

```
 book and this
```

It seems that the "array_distinct" cannot filter them out ?

thanks

Comment: Do have a look into the given link. It might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316783/python-dataframe-remove-duplicate-words-in-the-same-cell-within-a-column-in-pyt

Comment: `and` is not duplicated anywhere in the string. So based on what do you want to remove it? Or do you mean `book` and `this`? Can you show your desired final result?

Comment: it won't filter out anything because it's just an array of single string and not multiple strings so array_distinct just find one string in array. I assume you need to remove duplicate words from the string and not from the array of strings. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3448022, have you tried my answer and did it help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [lcase](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#lcase) , [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split) ,  [array_distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_distinct) and [array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_join) functions from pyspark `sql.functions`

For example, `F.expr("array_join(array_distinct(split(lcase(text),' ')),' ')")`

Here is working code

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df
.withColumn("text_new",
   F.expr("array_join(array_distinct(split(lcase(text),' ')),' ')")) \
.show(truncate=False)
```

**Explaination:**

Here, you first convert everthing to lower case with `lcase(text)` than split the array on whitespace with `split(text,' ')`, which produces

```
[i, like, this, book, and, this, book, be, downloaded, on, line]|
```

then you pass this to`array_distinct`, which produces

```
[i, like, this, book, and, be, downloaded, on, line]
```

and finally,  join it with whitespace using `array_join`

```
i like this book and be downloaded on line
```